# A program for short IDs and tagging capabilities

Tags: linux, knowledge-organization

I need a program, I have short numbers like problem IDs and I need a list/note/database-like application with high tagging capabilities, I mean like search engines; ie. you can search for numbers having both tags, or at least one, or exclude tags. I've searched a lot on the internet but the programs are mostly not good for these kind of searches. And I'm using ArchLinux OS so I will need an application which runs on linux.

EDIT: for more understanding of what I need, when I want to store a problem ID(4 characters long). It will be categorized due to different aspects, like difficuly, the idea of solving etc. I need to search these stored IDs having the features I noted above.

Comment: is there a reason not to use a database engine?  Elastic Search can do what you want I think.